# Get values from ApplicationSettings dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-config

In my App.config, the structure is like below:

```
<configuration>
 ...
 <applicationSettings>
  <someTab>
   <setting name="someName" serializeAs="String">
    <value>someValue</value>
   </setting>
   <setting name="otherName" serializeAs="String">
    <value>otherValue</value>
   </setting>
  </someTab>
 </applicationSettings>
<configuration>
```

I want to access each of the value dynamically (like a list or array or something).

I tried to use getSection from configurationManager:

```
var applicationSetting = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("applicationSettings/someTab") as NameValueCollection;
    foreach (var name in applicationSetting.AllKeys)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(name);
    }
```

but I got NullReferenceException, not sure if it's because of the different structure. The other I saw is like using add: `<add key="someName" value="someValue"></add>`

It would be great if I can access these values using a for loop or getting it into a list. Thank you.

--------------------------------------5/11/2019 12:08pm--------------------------------------------

I was trying to follow the approach 3 from this website, just that the app.config structure is different:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173468/Four-Ways-to-Read-Configuration-Setting-in-Csharp

Comment: @Fabio I still get the NullReferenceException. What if my tab is like `<someTab.something>`, do I just write `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("applicationSettings:someTab.something")`?

Comment: you are saying get keys but in your structure you have no keys. Have you tried the option which you have mentioned in your question? `<add key="someName" value="someValue"></add>`

Comment: @शेखर The setting was not created by me so I cannot change the structure.